# Get LinkedIn basic profile from someone through the LinkedIn URL

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

I would like to know if its possible to get the LinkedIn basic profile from someone ?

### Example

When I register a new user on the system, wish it were possible to get the basic information for this new user to note the URL of that person LinkedIn for example.

If it's possible, how can I do it with Javascript SDK ?

#### Code

```
// Setup an event listener to make an API call once auth is complete
function onLinkedInLoad() {
    IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", getProfileData);
}

// Handle the successful return from the API call
function onSuccess(data) {
    console.log(data);
}

// Handle an error response from the API call
function onError(error) {
    console.log(error);
}

// Use the API call wrapper to request the member's basic profile data
function getProfileData() {
    IN.API.Raw("/people/~").result(onSuccess).error(onError);
}
```

Comment: JavaScript does not have an SDK. I think you mean API. An SDK is a software development kit that provides tools for a software package. JavaScript is a language that is browser-dependent. An API on the other hand, is an abstract programming interface that lets you talk to another application.

Comment: [The Javascript SDK from Linkedin](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/signin-with-linkedin)

Comment: Most APIs will require you to sign-up for a key so that they can track your usage in the case where something goes awry and they need to know who did what (auditing purposes). You *might* get away with a JSONP request, but I have not looked into their API yet. You might want to check their [*"Getting started with the REST API"* page](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/rest-api). That might be more direct.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is covered in the LinkedIn documentation pretty well. If there is something more specific that you're looking for, you should clarify.

You should take a look at https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/js-sdk

The source you've linked looks like it's from https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/signin-with-linkedin, but if it's not you should look at that as well.